# Incorrect callback URL with oAuth 1.0a / Google

Tags: oauth, mashape

I'm trying to use oAuth 1.0a with Google to retrieve stuff (I can't use 2.0 for this use case).
I'm struggling at the authorization step because Google doesn't redirect my URL correctly and I was wondering what I am doing wrong. I am using the mashape-oauth node module (github.com/Mashape/mashape-oauth) to handle oauth stuff (signature, etc.).

Here is my code: https://github.com/jsilvestre/cozy-data-integrator/blob/master/server/controllers/integrator.coffee#L28-L49

Here is the result + chrome debugger information: http://d.pr/i/eQtK
The weird part is that Google redirects to /b/0/theencodedcallback instead of the callback itself.
Google oAuth 1.0 playground is working properly (it redirects to the callback URL and not /b/0/callbackurl).

Notice that I still have the same result even if I use a different callback URL.

Thank you in advance if you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the callback URL was encoded whereas it shouldn't be.

See https://github.com/Mashape/mashape-oauth/issues/3 all the details.